# Transform timestamp with keeping milliseconds

Tags: r, datetime, time, timestamp, anytime

I have a dataframe with timestamps, which look like this:

```
2020-06-28T16:45:04.3602059+03:00
```

I use anytime packages function anytime to transform its format:

```
df <- df %>%
    dplyr::mutate(
      timestamp = anytime::anytime(timestamp))
```

So after that timestamp looks like this:

```
2020-06-28 16:45:04
```

But i lost milliseconds here. How could i do that transformation with keeping milliseconds in case of this specific initial format?

Answer (score 0):

The milliseconds are preserved in the data, but the `POSIXct` class has a display method that truncates to the second. Using the `second()` function from the `lubridate` package, we can extract the seconds component of the `POSIXct` date.time and see that the milliseconds are still there:

```
library(anytime)
library(lubridate)
dt1 = anytime("2020-06-28T16:45:04.3602059+03:00")
second(dt1)
4.360205
```